# Freeradius is ignoring Packets

Tags: ubuntu, cisco, freeradius

currently i'm installing a Cisco ASR1k as an PPPoE BRAS.

I'm using freeradius as authentication service.
The setup is an Ubuntu 14.04LTS with a quite outdated freeradius 2.1.12 installed via APT.

```
freeradius: FreeRADIUS Version 2.1.12, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Aug 26 2015 at 14:47:03
```

Im running freeradius on an IPv6 socket.

The issue is that radius packets sent from the Cisco LAC Router are completely ignored and quite discarded. Running freeradius in -X debug mode only shows the message "Ready to process requests." beeing repeatead about every 10 Seconds.

TCPDUMP shows that Access request packets are being received, but not answered.

```
21:49:13.619711 IP6 2001:4cd8::X.21646 > 2001:4cd8::Y.1812: RADIUS, Access Request (1), id: 0x14 length: 145
21:49:18.653658 IP6 2001:4cd8::X.21646 > 2001:4cd8::Y.1812: RADIUS, Access Request (1), id: 0x14 length: 145
```

ufw is disabled, no iptables rules are applied.

Using radtest on localhost is successful as well as configuring an 'automate-tester' on the Cisco Box itself with the same user credentials.

So, i'dont think that there is a general fault in the configuration, but it seems that there are some attributes in the original Access-Request packet that causes the freeradius to ignore it completely.

freeradius -X shows absolutely no output.

Below you'll find a complete "debug radius verbose" output of the Cisco ASR, sorry for obfuscating the IPs.

```
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS/ENCODE(00001009):Orig. component type = PPPoE
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS: DSL line rate attributes successfully added
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS(00001009): Config NAS IP: X.X.X.X
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS(00001009): Config NAS IPv6: 2001:4CD8:::X
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS/ENCODE(00001009): acct_session_id: 4095
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS(00001009): sending
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS/ENCODE: Best Local IPv6-Address 2001:4CD8:::X for Radius-Server 2001:4CD8:::Y
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS(00001009): Send Access-Request to 2001:4CD8:::Y:1812 id 21646/94, len 145
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  authenticator E0 41 D9 2A 4B 76 67 34 - CA 07 D2 29 EB 04 56 F1
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  Framed-Protocol     [7]   6   PPP                       [1]
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  User-Name           [1]   12  "user-2"
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  User-Password       [2]   18  *
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  NAS-Port-Type       [61]  6   Virtual                   [5]
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  NAS-Port            [5]   6   0                         
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  NAS-Port-Id         [87]  12  "0/0/3/1996"
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  Vendor, Cisco       [26]  41  
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:   Cisco AVpair       [1]   35  "client-mac-address=0078.8827.6b03"
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  Service-Type        [6]   6   Framed                    [2]
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS:  NAS-IPv6-Address    [95]  18  2001:4CD8:::X
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS(00001009): Sending a IPv6 Radius Packet
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS: IPv6 udp send - source address: 2001:4CD8:::X, dest address: 2001:4CD8:::Y
Mar 15 21:08:44.983: RADIUS(00001009): Started 5 sec timeout
Mar 15 21:08:50.022: RADIUS(00001009): Request timed out! 
Mar 15 21:08:50.023: RADIUS: Retransmit to (2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813) for id 21646/94
Mar 15 21:08:50.023: RADIUS(00001009): Started 5 sec timeout
Mar 15 21:08:55.029: RADIUS(00001009): Request timed out! 
Mar 15 21:08:55.029: %RADIUS-4-RADIUS_DEAD: RADIUS server 2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813 is not responding.
Mar 15 21:08:55.029: RADIUS: Retransmit to (2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813) for id 21646/94
Mar 15 21:08:55.029: RADIUS(00001009): Started 5 sec timeout
Mar 15 21:08:55.030: %RADIUS-4-RADIUS_ALIVE: RADIUS server 2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813 is being marked alive.
Mar 15 21:09:00.063: RADIUS(00001009): Request timed out! 
Mar 15 21:09:00.063: RADIUS: Retransmit to (2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813) for id 21646/94
Mar 15 21:09:00.063: RADIUS(00001009): Started 5 sec timeout
Mar 15 21:09:05.105: RADIUS(00001009): Request timed out! 
Mar 15 21:09:05.105: RADIUS: Retransmit to (2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813) for id 21646/94
Mar 15 21:09:05.105: RADIUS(00001009): Started 5 sec timeout
Mar 15 21:09:10.152: RADIUS(00001009): Request timed out! 
Mar 15 21:09:10.153: RADIUS: Retransmit to (2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813) for id 21646/94
Mar 15 21:09:10.153: RADIUS(00001009): Started 5 sec timeout
Mar 15 21:09:15.159: RADIUS(00001009): Request timed out! 
Mar 15 21:09:15.159: RADIUS: No response from (2001:4CD8:::Y:1812,1813) for id 21646/94
Mar 15 21:09:15.159: RADIUS/DECODE: No response from radius-server; parse response; FAIL
Mar 15 21:09:15.159: RADIUS/DECODE: Case error(no response/ bad packet/ op decode);parse response; FAIL
```

Any idea how to isolate or to solve this issue?

Best Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

If FreeRADIUS is showing absolutely no debug output, then the server is not receiving the packets from the kernel, or you have it listening on the wrong port.

Trace using `radsniff -i <interface>`.  It will show any packets received on UDP ports 1812/1813.

If you see packets, verify `netstat -lun | grep 181[23]` shows FreeRADIUS is listening on those ports.

Also verify the reverse routing path for the packet is the same interface as it was received on or disable RPS (http://www.slashroot.in/linux-kernel-rpfilter-settings-reverse-path-filtering).

Comment: Hi Arran, thanks for your comment. i don't think that uRPF or some Filtering on the Machine itself was the cause of my problems. Using radsniff provided me the way to the solution. - It seems that radsniff in the version i installed was not able to handyle IPv6 packets. So i decided to purge Freeradius 2.1.21 from the Box and installed freeradius 3.0. - This solved all problems, everything is running fine now.

Comment: Yes, v6 was added to radsniff in v3.0.0.  The server should have been able to process IPv6 packets, but possibly not a version that old.  I think it was added part way through v2.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem by upgrading to freeradius 3.0.